# Why my csv file shows "Error! output.csv is not UTF-8 encoded"?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I want to convert my array to csv file. I have an array named result.

```
result = ['Prenzlauer Berg Nordwest' 'Neuköllner Mitte/Zentrum' 'Rixdorf' ...
          'Parkviertel' 'Frankfurter Allee Süd FK' 'Helmholtzplatz']
```

I try to write an array to csv file using `np.savetxt('output.csv', result, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')`

But, in my csv file shows

```
Error! output.csv is not UTF-8 encoded. Saving disabled. See console for more details.
```

How do i fix this?

Thank youu

Comment: please provide your code sample here. Are you using jupyter notebook?

Comment: the variable named result is a result from some process, and the datatype is numpy array.
I only use this np.savetxt('output.csv', result, delimiter=',', fmt='%s') to convert.

Yes, i'm using jupyter

Comment: Try `np.savetxt('output.csv', result, delimiter=',', fmt='%s', encoding='utf-8')` and try your code also with command shell if it did not work with jupyter. without your sample array it is hard to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It shows "EOL while scanning string literal"

Comment: I missed a quote at the end of it. edited it. please try again.

Comment: Okaay, thank you so much. I've done thiss :)))

Comment: neither of them solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you open the csv file in Excel and save as "CSV UTF-8(Comma delimited)(*.csv)", it works perfectly. I just did that and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The csv file you are using likely does not support UTF-8 text formatting so some special characters might not work. Try following these steps to turn on utf-8 encoding in your csv file: https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-save-csv-excel-file-as-utf-8-encoded/

Or try creating a new csv file. I think np can set the csv file to the correct type automatically upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

In an `ipython` session running in `linux`, your code works:

```
In [50]: result = ['Prenzlauer Berg Nordwest', 'Neuköllner Mitte/Zentrum', 'Rixdorf', 
    ...:           'Parkviertel', 'Frankfurter Allee Süd FK', 'Helmholtzplatz']                        
In [51]: result = np.array(result)                                                                     
In [52]: result                                                                                        
Out[52]: 
array(['Prenzlauer Berg Nordwest', 'Neuköllner Mitte/Zentrum', 'Rixdorf',
       'Parkviertel', 'Frankfurter Allee Süd FK', 'Helmholtzplatz'],
      dtype='<U24')
In [53]: np.savetxt('output.csv', result, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')                                     
In [54]: cat output.csv                                                                                
Prenzlauer Berg Nordwest
Neuköllner Mitte/Zentrum
Rixdorf
Parkviertel
Frankfurter Allee Süd FK
Helmholtzplatz
```

And in an editor the file type is utf8.